# How to save a full webpage from RoboBrowser

Tags: save, robobrowser

I am fairly new to python and RoboBrowser. In fact for what I want to do, I do not know if Robobrowser is the correct solution. I need to scrape and save web pages from my county assessors office. The web page to submit and return are aspx.

I go to this page first:
https://apps.summitcountyco.gov/NOVArchiveViewer/
and fill in a schedule number, and then the browser returns this page
https://apps.summitcountyco.gov/NOVArchiveViewer/viewer.aspx

I am running python 3.8 on wsl 2 (windows 11)

Here is my code:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
url = "https://apps.summitcountyco.gov/NOVArchiveViewer/default.aspx"
browser = RoboBrowser(history = True)
browser.open(url)
form = browser.get_form(id='aspnetForm')
form['ctl00$pageBaseContent$txtPropertySchedule'].value = '1501134'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

I then do

```
print(form)
<RoboForm __VIEWSTATE=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, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=4901F91F, __EVENTVALIDATION=/wEdABKPEpAhzQjkVFwnPT9187ykJmix/RXtpz2Ljh318L+c7SaUqHiuabDygW/1N0Ll7QWuXUXjSj0V40oqtS0eK/deNionNqW0Huk3vArFBrRTPt9zwF4KMz1bz6oBLBztN99subxrK7NOLUEjf2Z481lSLM0Ds+M6qxRIgy4Owu8LeVHBPa/BDvzfJzgEeKjRxw5DvzimRXReDagzD3M8uCg+yXSHFGt2x/AhvF8BraqfKyYnVCVY7O88ZyRUt40okt6at8WDO7fVjrGu7Lg71d1dwwHIL/HCHjF+LE319Osvvi6hIjCj6Ta/3IpgjuU74Eh/4T/e28PICWkdL1NiFQzzxTSWB6r8I2K3otxvTMbzPclgrqTLFPZsS2dVm43WUiRN5Sl4s+RLl00KGojfSo/EO/f64LR5l2RJGMLWVsTOpQ==, ctl00$pageBaseContent$txtPropertySchedule=1501134, ctl00$pageBaseContent$ddlTaxYear=2023, ctl00$pageBaseContent$btnSearch=Search>
```

and the schedule is submitted I think properly

and this

```
print(browser)
<RoboBrowser url=https://apps.summitcountyco.gov/NOVArchiveViewer/viewer.aspx>
```

says I am on the new page.

My problem is I want to save this page locally to my computer. Each schedule is going to come up somewhat differently, and I need to look at many of them to consider how to scrape certain elements.  How can I just save the viewer.aspx page?

Thanks
Don

I have not found any syntax to save a full page, like a wget.

Answer (score 0):

after more searching, I made a crude hack to do what I want.

I added panda, then added this code:

```
form.html = str(browser.parsed)
print(form.html) > test.html
```